# Is this parametric equation correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, parametric, matrix-equations

Am I able to just put the planes point into the equation and leave it at that? or am I wrong here?

[image]

My  parametric equation:

(x,y,z) = (3,-2,1)+  t(2,1,-3) + s(1,-2,4)

Answer (score 1):

Incorrect; that parametric plane does not include the point $(1,-2,4)$!

But you can use $(x,y,z) = s(3,-2,1)+ t(2,1,-3) + (1-s)(1,-2,4)=s(2,0,-3)+ t(2,1,-3) +  (1,-2,4)$

Now it is easy to see that for s=t=0 the plane includes $(1,-2,4)$, and for $s=1$ you get points over the line.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, It's stated that the plane contains the point (1, -2, 4) and also contains the line (in the parametric equation)

Comment: For what choices of s and t do you think your parametric equation gives (x,y,z)=(1,-2,4)? if there are no such s and t (there aren't), then the plane does not include that point.

Comment: Ok thanks, one other thing I don't fully understand - how come you have (1 - s)? Where is this from?

Comment: I just tried to combine two parameters so that I would get the line for some values and the point for others, and luckily it was easy. I am pretty sure there must be a recipe for it, but I do not remember it, I left college a long time ago.